# Is it possible to use EC2 and AWS Certificate Manager only?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-certificate-manager

I have my websites deployed on ec2 instance and was planning to use SSL/TLS certificate using AWS Certificate Manager. I found this link saying I may have to use Load Balancer to use the SSL from ACM. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-services.html. Is it possible to just use EC2 and ACM not including the Load Balancer.

I know I can buy a certificate from other sites and install the ssl through EC2 instead. But I was just thinking if I can have it all on AWS.

Any pointers is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No I don't think its possible, because the certificate itself is stored in AWS Infrastructure and only referenced via ARN, besides AWS takes care of rotating the certificate and that cannot be achieved via a manual process.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortuntely No there is no direct way to use it on EC2 Instance.

But it can achieved if you put EC2(Single Instance also) Behind Load Balancer and attach Certificate to LB then you will get https.

Thanks

Comment: hi, so my other options will be buy an SSL certificate from other vendor and install the SSL to ec2. right? Sorry, first time setting up SSL/TLS. Also the client doesn't want any more charges, using LB you may need to pay hourly..

Comment: No you do not need to pay anything for ELB , you only pay for ec2 this way you would not need to buy ssl from third party and use aws ssl for free

Comment: @KushVyas ELB is not free.

Comment: Yes @Michael-sqlbot thank you for pointing out.